# How to trigger a keypress event in javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, events

i have an input id : myinput i want to trigger a keypress event but without any use of jQuery

Comment: An HTML INPUT control has an onkeypress event `<input id="myinput" type="text" onkeypress="myJSFunction()">` You just put the JavaScript code to execute inside the onkeypress attribute value.

Comment: im not searching for relying the event to the input

Comment: i want a code that do the same as trigger function in jQuery but without using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener to the input for example

```
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
myinput.addEventListener('keypress',function(){
  //code ...
});
```

If keypress is not exactly what you looking for there is keydown, keyup, input for diffrent events.

Comment: im not searching for relying the event to the input , i want a code that do the same as trigger function in jQuery but without using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onkeypress" HTML event and call a javascript function like "myFunction()".

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
     //you code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: im not searching for relying the event to the input , i want a code that do the same as trigger function in jQuery but without using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add "onkeypress" then add event listener. But if you want to trigger event then you could:

```
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
if (myinput.onkeypress) {
    myinput.onkeypress()
}
```

Comment: im not searching for relying the event to the input , i want a code that do the same as trigger function in jQuery but without using jQuery

Comment: So calling myinput.onkeypress() is not working for you?

Comment: how decide the charCode in this case ?